# Javascript not calling in Brave Browser

Tags: javascript, html, brave

I have a function that works on all browsers except for Brave Browser. Any idea why?

There is a form that calls a function to redirect to a new URL with the user's input. It's not doing anything when called in a brave browser. It's works on all other browsers. this is being called from a Wordpress site. Could this have anything to do with it?

```
    <form id="url-10">
            <input id="red-border-error-2" class="url10-form" type="text" name="urlName-10">
            <input class="url10-button" type="submit" value="Build your app"></input>
        </form> 
<div id="error-message-10"></div>

<script>
    // JavaScript goes here

    
    
        document.getElementById("url-10").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault()
                let errorMessage = document.getElementById("red-border-error-2").placeholder = " Type your store URL here ";
                let x = document.getElementById("red-border-error-2");
                let myForm = document.getElementById("url-10");
                let formData = new FormData(myForm);
                if (formData.get("urlName-10") === "") {
                return x.classList.add('placeholder-red-text');
                errorMessage;
                }
                else{
                    EndOfUrl = sanitizeDomainInput(formData.get("urlName-10"));
                    newUrl = redirectLink(EndOfUrl);
                    markConversionAndRedirect(newUrl);
                    return false;
                }

            });

            function markConversionAndRedirect(newUrl) {
                    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                        'send_to': 'G-Q0HF9N3DYR/connect_square',
                        'event_callback': function () { window.location.href = newUrl }

                    })
                };


            function sanitizeDomainInput(input) {
                input = input || 'unknown.com'
                if (input.startsWith('http://')) {
                    input = input.substr(7)
                }
                if (input.startsWith('https://')) {
                    input = input.substr(8)
                }
                var regexp = new RegExp(/^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$/)
                return regexp.test(input) ? input : 'unknown.com';


            };

            function redirectLink(domain) {
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                const refValue = urlParams.get('ref'); 
                return `https://dashboard.getorda.com/signup/?state=${domain}` + (refValue ? `_${ refValue }` : '');
            };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's because Brave is blocking the `gtag.js` library you're using. Because your redirection is happening inside of the `gtag` callback function that means Brave will never execute this code.

You can modify your `markConversationAndRedirect` function so it'll work even if `gtag` is blocked. See below.

```js
function markConversionAndRedirect(newUrl) {
  if (typeof gtag !== 'undefined') {
    // gtag is loaded, we can safely use it
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'G-Q0HF9N3DYR/connect_square',
      'event_callback': function () { window.location.href = newUrl }
    })
  } else {
    // gtag didnt load, redirect anyway
    window.location.href = newUrl
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Could be the issue but I pasted your code and still not responding... :/

Comment: Anything in your browser console when you use the form?

Comment: In my case gtag is loaded but inside callback execution is blocked by brave

Comment: This worked for me, in a case where the gtag function I was calling in an onclick event was   

goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    window.google_is_call = true;
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }

by making the first IF execution

goog_report_converstion(newURL)

the link successfully executes in the Brave browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a custom timeout and return a promise. In Brave, the timeout will be exceeded and the promise will reject, you can then run custom code on the catch block, or to have the same behaviour across run it in the finally block. Example:

```
/* Sends Google Analytics event with custom timeout and returns a promise */
export function sendGAEventWithTimeout(eventName, threshold) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => reject(), threshold);

    window.gtag('event', eventName, {
      send_to: 'G-Q0HF9N3DYR/connect_square',
      event_callback: (...args) => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        resolve(...args);
      }
    });
  });
}

/* Run different code depending on if it fails (aka you are in Brave) or not */
sendGAEventWithTimeout('conversion', 1000)
  .then((result) => {
    window.location.href = newUrl;
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // This will run on Brave or any other browser that blocks GA
  });

/* Run same code on both cases */
sendGAEventWithTimeout('conversion', 1000)
  .finally(() => {
    window.location.href = newUrl;
  });
```